# Correct way of computing dice score for image segmentation?

Tags: deep-learning, convolutional-neural-network, computer-vision, image-segmentation, semantic-segmentation

In binary image segmentation, for given a set of images, it's true mask and predicted mask. How do you compute dice score? Should I compute the dice score for each image separately and then find mean across all images? Or compute the dice score for all images at once by flattening tensor? Which is the correct way?

Comment: Does an event happen? If so in each image or over the set of images?

Comment: Event happens over a subset of images. There can be multiple events, but each image can only belong to a single event

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is to compute the DICE score per image and then find the mean, median and STD across all test images. It is good practice to report all three metrics to provide a clear intuition to the reader.

For more details, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58583829/2127561).